# Inhibit clang tail call elimination

Tags: c, optimization, clang

Is there any command line option to clang to inhibit only tail call elimination? I did find [this](https://reviews.llvm.org/D43841) but it looks like it is for Objective-C.

Here are more details of my requirement.

So instead of something like this (that I get with clang -g -O2):

```
000000000000a9f0 <_vgw00000ZZ_libthrZdsoZa_pthreadZucreate>:
a9f0: 55 push %rbp
a9f1: 48 89 e5 mov %rsp,%rbp
a9f4: 5d pop %rbp
a9f5: eb 09 jmp aa00
a9f7: 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
a9fe: 00 00
```

I would like to get something similar to GCC:

```
000000000000999f <_vgw00000ZZ_libthrZdsoZa_pthreadZujoin>:
999f: 55 push %rbp
99a0: 48 89 e5 mov %rsp,%rbp
99a3: e8 a5 c1 ff ff callq 5b4d
99a8: 5d pop %rbp
99a9: c3 retq
```

(The reason for this is that during execution I need to do some stack walking and the tail call optimization effectively reduces the call stack by one, and that is making a mess in the regression tests. I don't think that this tiny optimization is worth the maintenance overhead).

I realize that I could change the code to be something like the following, but my preference is for a
file-specific change to the Makefile.

```
__attribute__((optnone)) \
ret_ty I_WRAP_SONAME_FNNAME_ZZ(VG_Z_LIBPTHREAD_SONAME,f)(args)
```

(excuse the funky macros, the second line is the 1st line of the function definition).

Comment: Not sure about clang, but in gcc, TCO should be disabled with `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`. clang tends to take the same set of options as gcc, so worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try for real later, I just did a quick test and at least clang doesn't complain that it is not recognized.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. clang accepts the option (possibly to be compatible) but seems to have silently ignored it.